# Not able to understand difference of function in class & defining it as prototype in Javascript OOP

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm not able to understand what exactly is the difference by defining the function inside the class function & defining it as prototype. Here is my code.

### PART 1

```
function myContent() {

    this.toUserID = "1234";
    this.loadMainLabel = function(url) {
        alert("url:"+url);
    }       
}

var objMyContent = new myContent();
objMyContent.loadMainLabel("www.google.com");
```

### PART 2

```
function myContent() {

    this.toUserID = "1234";          
}

var objMyContent = new myContent();
myContent.prototype.loadMainLabel = function(url) {
    alert(url);
}
objMyContent.loadMainLabel("www.google.com");
```

Both gives the same output.. But, what exactly is the difference? Any thoughts would be appreciable.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You are defining the object as a prototype in both cases. In several other languages, you define a class for an object (Not an object itself) and then create objects as instances of that class.

- **Class**

  Define methods and properties, but is different from an instance of that class. Objects are then created as instances of the class.
- **Prototype**

  Define a prototype object and then create spin-off objects from that prototype. The prototype is an example of that kind of object rather than a definition of that kind of object.

See this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) for a more detailed explanation of the difference

Comment: This subject has been answered over and over again, already. Please just mark it as [an duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript), as there are plenty of excellent answers out there.